# MySQL: How does nullable columns function in joint index?

Tags: mysql, indexing

I have two columns in a MySQL table,  one is startDay varchar(10)，like "2020-03-23", the other is orderId archer(20), both of them are nullable

If I create a joint index on (orderId, startDay)

```
  select * from table where orderId is null and startDay < '2020-03-23'

  select * from table where orderId is not null and startDay < '2020-03-23'
```

for the above 2 sql statements, I have two questions:
1) does the first statement use both columns in the joint index? since there are tens of millions of rows, if the statement doesn't use both, but only use part of the index (namely the first one), then the performance may be low?

2) the second one can't use the joint index? why?

Comment: use EXPLAIN on both queries to what mysql uses

Comment: @nbk seems explain doesn't tell us how many columns in a joint index are used?

Comment: without viewing the explain result, it is quite hard to tell. what your database does, it is besides a create table a possibility to see what is used see last column

Comment: @nbk 1 SIMPLE bill NULL ref idx_repaid_time,idx_due_date_status,i_d_r i_d_r 7 const 13 45.00 Using index condition

Comment: That is the EXPLAIN for both querys?

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.  And put the `EXPLAINs` (for each query) in your question, with the columns lined up.

Answer (score 1):

The first can make full use of the index because it only has one range-based condition, and that is for the latter field in the index.

Basically, it goes *something like* this:

- `orderId IS NULL` looks for a specific node in the index identifying all IS NULL entries,
- that node's child nodes are effectively sorted by startDay (the second part of the index)
- the **range** of startDay nodes where `startDay < '2020-03-23'` are easily identified.

With the second query, `orderId IS NOT NULL` basically identifies every first tier node other than the one that identifies the `IS NULL` orderId values.... and the MySQL won't go further with the indexing. (It stops at the first ranged condition).

Also, it's not so much a matter of having a nullable column so much as the first query has the equivalent of an `=` condition, and the second has a `<>` condition.

Comment: seems `explain` doesn't tell us how many columns in a joint index are used?

Comment: I do not believe so... just which index (if any) is used.

Comment: Yep, typically indexes won't use inequality-like operators. as in the second case.

Comment: @Uueerdo - You can _usually_ deduce from `Key_len` how many columns are used (INT NOT NULL: 4, INT NULL: 5, etc).  However Key_len does not include the columns used for `ORDER BY`.  Need to see `EXPLAIN FORMAT=JSON` for that.